# ¿Se deberían traducir los mensajes de error que forman parte de las preguntas?

Tags: discusión

[La primera pregunta que he publicado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1/la-creaci%C3%B3n-manual-de-un-alias-de-ruta-con-un-directrouteprovider-personalizado) se titula *La creación manual de un alias de ruta con un DirectRouteProvider personalizado causa un error “Multiple actions were found that match the request”*. Ese es el mensaje de error tal como me lo da el IDE. Mi duda es, ¿deberíamos publicar estos mensajes de error tal cual se obtienen, o deberíamos publicarlos traducidos? (por ejemplo *"Se han encontrado múltiples acciones que coinciden con la petición"* en este caso)

Comment: hay usar el idioma original para que otros puedan encontrar la pregunta/respuesta en el futuro.

Comment: creo que el error debe estar como lo obtienes porque es lo que estas acostumbrado a ver cuando por ejemple en compilador te dice algo, ya se en ingles que es lo mas habitual o en ruso de ser lo normal, por lo menos esa es mi opinión, y lo que comente rnrneverdies es super hacertado

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Mi opinión:

En general, no hace sentido traducir errores o otro texto producido de programas.  Traducir esas cosas lo hace imposible buscar las preguntas por Google o otra forma de busca.

La mayoría de la gente van a buscar el texto exacto.  Y aun que alguien lo traduzca antes de buscar, no hay garantía que van a traducirlo en la misma forma que yo.

En otro lado, a veces, tal vez, hace sentido traducir el texto *junto con* el texto original. Eso, normalmente, sería el caso con mensajes grandes, complicados, y no regulares.

Comment: yo estoy de acuerdo en que el texto de los mensajes debe ser el original que uno obtiene, o el mas común, por que si tu tienes un IDE que muestra mensajes traducido puede que te sea mas dificil encontrar una respuesta por ejemplo en google que si usas el texto original, tambien rnrneverdies cita una muy buena razón Saludos

Comment: Coincido en utilizar el idioma original - que ojalá sea inglés. Cada vez que tengo errores con las funciones traducidas de Excel se me llevan los demonios.

Answer (score 2):

Me gustaría dejar los errores en inglés dado el case que esto es lo mas "normal." Pero, en caso que un usuario llega a tener la buena suerte de encontrarse leyendo un error en español se vale el preguntar aquí.

Answer (score 1):

Yo creo que ambos son válidos.

Por ejemplo en algunos centros de labores te instalan tantos los IDEs o runtimes en español.

Si has tenido esta "suerte" vas a recibir los mensajes de error en español.

Por otro lado es común que las personas (me incluyo) también tengan o prefieran la versión en inglés y por lo tanto reciban los mensajes de error en inglés.

Yo creo dos preguntas con el mismo mensaje de error pero en idiomas distintos (aunque obviamente solo inglés y español) son igualmente válidas y la segunda en aparecer (sea español o inglés) puede ser cerrada como duplicada de la primera.

Comment: En mi opinión, recibir un mensaje de error en español es en realidad _mala suerte_, pues tus chances de encontrar información sobre el problema son mucho menores. Por suerte, ¡ya estamos aquí!

Answer (score 0):

En mi opinión, deberían conservarse los mensajes de error y stacktraces en inglés debido a que es un idioma más universal y en general esto facilitaría la búsqueda de soluciones porque la documentación es más extensiva en ese idioma.

Sin embargo, para propósitos de contextualización para quienes no dominan el inglés, debería proveerse la traducción a español, ya sea por parte de quien hace la pregunta, o de alguno de los comentaristas o quienes respondan (solo si es lo suficientemente hábil para proporcionar la traducción exacta, porque si es una traducción automática al estilo de Google Translate se puede perder contexto o sentido y pierde todo su propósito)

Considero que esta traducción debería usar alguna notación especial (algo parecido a cuando uno transcribe código fuente), pero no sé si en este espacio exista alguna marcación especial que lo permita. Esto puede ser tema para un debate posterior.

Ejemplo:

Si el mensaje de error es:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 5, Size: 5
at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(ArrayList.java:507)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:324)
at MiClase.buscar(MiClase.java:1093)
at MiClase.submit(MiClase.java:1002)
```

Debería traducirse la parte más relevante, o sea la parte inicial:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 5, Size: 5
```

como

> Excepción de índice fuera de los límites: Índice: 5, Tamaño: 5

Noten que no necesariamente se haría de forma literal a como aparece en el mensaje original sino más bien en términos que sean fáciles de entender para quien no sepa inglés o encuentre demasiado críptico el mensaje.

En resumen, mi sugerencia es: conservar los mensajes en inglés sin modificación y proporcionar siempre una traducción a español (contextualizada, no automática) de los mismos.